# how to reflect an object about a plane?

Tags: unity-game-engine

given a plane gameobject, I would like to reflect an object about that plane

a simple case of this would be a plane at 0,0,0 with no rotation with the object at 0,-1,0 which results in a reflected position on 0,1,0

a more complex case, is the plane at 0,0,0 with rotation on the x-axis of 45` with the object at 0,-1,-1 which results in a reflected position on 0,1,1

I'm looking for a solution that can take any case of a plane in any position with any rotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Plane.ClosestPointOnPlane](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.ClosestPointOnPlane.html) to get the according position on the plane.

Therefore you need to create a [`Plane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.html) first. As `inNormal` you have to use a vector perpendicular to the planes surface.

- For a `Quad` Primitive this is the negative `forward` vector
- for a `Plane` Primitive it is the `up` vector instead.

Than you can simply use the Vector between the original object and that `ClosestPointOnPlane` in order to move to the same relative position but with an inverted Vector:

```c#
public class ReflectPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Source;
    public Transform Plane;

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        // create a plane object representing the Plane
        var plane = new Plane(-Plane.forward, Plane.position);

        // get the closest point on the plane for the Source position
        var mirrorPoint = plane.ClosestPointOnPlane(Source.position);

        // get the position of Source relative to the mirrorPoint
        var distance = Source.position - mirrorPoint;

        // Move from the mirrorPoint the same vector but inverted
        transform.position = mirrorPoint - distance;
    }
}
```

Result (blue ball has this component attached and reflects white balls position)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I use:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Mirror point to opposite side of a plane
  /// </summary>
  public static Vector3 Mirror(this Vector3 point, Plane plane)
    => 2f * plane.ClosestPointOnPlane(point) - point;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Vector3.ProjectOnPlane](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ProjectOnPlane.html) like this:

```
//I used a cube and a quad. So i am finding the projection of cube's position onto quad
public GameObject cube;
private Vector3 point;
private Vector3 projectedPoint;
void Start () {
    point = cube.transform.position;
    planeOrigin = gameObject.transform.position;
    Vector3 v = point - planeOrigin;
    Vector3 d = Vector3.Project(v, -gameObject.transform.forward);
    projectedPoint = point - d;
}   

void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawLine(point, projectedPoint);
}
```

You can see how it works from the image below:

[image]

Then you can calculate the reflection by calculating direction between point and projected point  and multiplying it with two times of distance between them like this:

```
 Vector3 reflection = point + 2*(projectedPoint - point);
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, that only seems to work if the plane is at 0,0,0.... any thoughts about it how would work for a plane at any location?